# Detect dual display/monitor using Carbon Framework in mac?

Tags: c, macos, xul, macos-carbon, xulrunner

Is there an API present in Carbon Framework to detect dual monitor.

I would like to find this for my xulrunner application? I would like to know if second monitor is present before I launch my application in mac.

I need this because I am doing a kiosk kind of application.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`nsIScreenManager` service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIScreenManager) for that:

```js
var screenManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/gfx/screenmanager;1"]
                              .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScreenManager);
alert(screenManager.numberOfScreens);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess I cannot capture(disable or fill black) secondary/external display device.

Comment: Oh really, Can you tell me how can I get the secondary monitor/screen.

Comment: I guess that you would call `nsIScreenManager.screenForRect` with coordinates just outside the primary screen (there doesn't seem to be a way to get all the screens directly).